# adding math formula string to document using javascript and MathJax

Tags: javascript, html, string, mathjax

When pressing the button to add the math formula, the MathJax statement does not seem to be interpretet:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('go');
button.addEventListener('click', displayMath, true);

function displayMath() {
    const body = document.body;
    p = document.createElement('p');
    const a = 3, b = 2;
    const c = a + b;
    const math = "\\(" + a + "+ " + b + " = " + c + "\\)";
    p.innerHTML = math;
    body.appendChild(p);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" async
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML" async>
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>press the button to display math like this: \(a + b = c\)</p>
        <button id="go" type="button">Go!</button>
        
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

1) Can MathJax statements be addet through events like a button click?

2) If not are there better alternatives?

I appreciate any help, thanks :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run Mathjax parser again, to convert dynamically added expression to math. Here is [documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html).
So, what you need to do is run `MathJax.Hub.Queue();` method on your new expression. Your code should looks like this:

```
const button = document.getElementById('go');
button.addEventListener('click', displayMath, true);

function displayMath() {
    const body = document.body;
    p = document.createElement('p');
    const a = 3, b = 2;
    const c = a + b;
    const math = "\\(" + a + "+ " + b + " = " + c + "\\)";
    p.innerHTML = math;
    body.appendChild(p);
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, p]);
}
```

And [here is working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ztdx3ge/)

Comment: thanks a lot, suspected something like this but could not find the method. awesome!